# Use of taxonomy in sandbox

Tags: sandbox-solution, taxonomy

I am discovering sandbox mode and already have a limitation issue.
I
 can't use the assembly `Taxonomy`

I've a treeview in a term store and I have to retrieve or set a value.

What can I use as column in place of taxonomy, but with a treeview?

And how can I do this in sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

`Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.dll` is not allowed in sandbox solution and that's why you're getting an exception. You can get string value of managed metadata field by calling `GetFormattedValue`:

```
string value = spItem.GetFormattedValue(field.InternalName);
```

Comment: are there a way to have a tree value like parent/child/value selected